# check for string after a string

Tags: java, regex, string, jakarta-ee, pattern-matching

I'm writing a logic to check if there is any number following a specific keyword ("top" in the case).

```
String test = "top 10 results";
String test = "show top 10 results";
```

I used the pattern match find to acheive that  and its working.

```
public static boolean hasNumberafterTOP(String query)
{
    boolean hasNumberafterTOP = false;
    Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("top\\s+([0-9]+)");
    Matcher matcher = pat.matcher(query);
        if(matcher.find())
        {
            hasNumberafterTOP = true;
            numberAfterTOP=matcher.group(1);
        }


    return hasNumberafterTOP;       
}
```

Is there any way I can extend this check to include these words too. five,ten,twenty,thirty etc.?

Comment: `([0-9]+|one|two|three)` etc. You'll be there for a while.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
String keyword = "top";
Pattern p= Pattern.compile("\\d*\\s+"+Pattern.quote(keyword));
Matcher match = p.matcher(query");
match .find();
String inputInt = makeMatch.group();
System.out.println(inputInt);
```